# Pointers and references (convert char to LPCWSTR)

Tags: c++, glut

Here I'm resolving an error which occurs in VS2013, while working with Glut-library. As I see - it is a simple problem with pointers and references. So, the output for the 11th line is:

```
## error C2664: 'AUX_RGBImageRec *auxDIBImageLoadW(LPCWSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [13]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Where is the mistake? It must be a (*) sign missed in the 11th line.

```
void TextureInit()
{
 char strFile[]="Particle.bmp";
 AUX_RGBImageRec *pImage;
 /* Выравнивание в *.bmp по байту */
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
 /* Создание идентификатора для текстуры */
 glGenTextures(1,&TexId[0]);
 /* Загрузка изображения в память */

 pImage = auxDIBImageLoad(strFile);

 /* Начало описания свойств текстуры */
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,TexId[0]);
 /* Создание уровней детализации и инициализация текстуры
  */
 gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_RGB,pImage->sizeX,
                   pImage->sizeY,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                   pImage->data);

 /* Задание параметров текстуры */
 /* Повтор изображения по параметрическим осям s и t */
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
 /* Не использовать интерполяцию при выборе точки на
 * текстуре
  */
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 /* Совмещать текстуру и материал объекта */
 glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
}
```

Comment: Read about [`std::mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs). Or use wide characters to begin with.

Comment: Project Properties/General - change your character set to MBCS.  It defaults to Unicode, which is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you do not *intend* to use the Unicode libraries. In this case, remove the macro definition of _UNICODE and UNICODE in the project properties, and use _MBCS instead. This, however, makes more likely that the characters can go wrong on Windows machines that use a different locale.

Generally speaking, one should not directly use char or wchar_t to interface with the Windows API. For maximum compatibility, you should wrap them in the _T macro. Instead of writing

```
char strFile[]="Particle.bmp";
```

write

```
TCHAR strFile[]=_T("Particle.bmp");
```

Consult Microsoft documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a pointer/reference problem, it's a string encoding problem. `auxDIBImageLoadW` takes an`LPCWSTR` - a `UTF-16` string. You're trying to pass it an `ASCII` string.

To fix this, declare `strFile` as `wchar_t strFile[] = L"Particle.bmp";`.

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode builds (which have been the default since VS2005), `auxDIBImageLoad()` is expanded to `auxDIBImageLoadW()` (the ending `W` stands for *Wide characters*, i.e `wchar_t`s), which is the Unicode UTF-16 version of the API.

The `strFile` argument that you passed to `auxDIBImageLoadW()` is instead a `char`-string (not a `wchar_t` string), defined as:

> ```
> char strFile[]="Particle.bmp";
> ```

So you have a mismatch in the string parameter.

An option is to just define `strFile` as a `wchar_t` string (note also the `L` prefix to define the string literal):

```
wchar_t strFile[] = L"Particle.bmp";
```

Or, if for some reason you must have a `char` string, you can convert it at the call site, using the [ATL helper macro `CA2W`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) (which converts from `A`ansi - i.e. `char`-string - to `W`ide Unicode UTF-16 `wchar_t` string):

```
#include <atlconv.h> // for CA2W

// char strFile[]...
pImage = auxDIBImageLoad(CA2W(strFile));
```

(The `CA2W` is a convenient RAII wrapper around the `::MultiByteToWideChar()` Win32 API.)

Answer (score 0):

Noone of the methods could resolve. But funally I came to another part, which I've moved to another topic:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064256/opening-a-bmp-with-auxdibimageload-within-glut-library][1]